# What is this the name of this "Edit Widget" view (for iOS 14 widgets) & how can I define something like this?

Tags: configuration, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

When I hold (long press) a widget in iOS 14, a popup menu appears & when I tap on the `Edit Widget` item, the widgets flip into a configuration view.

I want to create a configuration view like that, but I have no idea what is this & how can I define something like it.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your Widget configurable you need to use `IntentConfiguration` (instead of `StaticConfiguration`).

From [Making a Configurable Widget](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget):

> To add configurable properties to your widget:
>
> 1. Add a custom intent definition that defines the configurable properties to your Xcode
>    project.
> 2. Use an IntentTimelineProvider in your widget to incorporate
>    the user’s choices into your timeline entries.
> 3. If the properties rely
>    on dynamic data, implement an Intents extension.

Useful links:

- [Creating a Widget Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/creating-a-widget-extension)
- [Making a Configurable Widget](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget)

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but are some classes missing from both articles? I Assume they are not but possibly referenced elsewhere? The View Classes near the end of "Creating a Widget Extension" like `GameTurnSummary`, `GameStatusWithLastTurnResult`, etc.. are not there. Any suggestions? Same with some of the stuff mentioned in "Making a Configurable Widget".  I know you didn't write the articles, just thought I would ask here.

Comment: @AlanS I assume they may be referencing parts of their demo project which is available here: [Building Widgets Using WidgetKit and SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/building_widgets_using_widgetkit_and_swiftui)